# How can I add a If statement in solr within my boostQuery in solr?

Tags: solr

I have a variable color .I want to add a bq only if the variable color has red in it :
ex: I want something like this

```
 if(color==="red"){
    bq=Category:Shoes^120
  }
```

like

```
bq: "if(exists(query({!v='GraphNode:cream'})),(Color:cream^120),(Color:cream^80))"
```

doesnt work ? any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you want to give a multiplicative boost of 120 for documents that have `red` in field `color` and `Shoes` in field `category`, you can use the Boolean [and function](https://wiki.apache.org/solr/FunctionQuery#and) like this (new lines only for clarity):

```
{!boost b="if(and(exists(query({!v='color:red'})),
                  exists(query({!v='category:Shoes'}))
                 ),120,1
             )
          "
}(YOUR_QUERY)
```

Comment: I want it to be additive ...moreover I dont want it to be placed in the query field ..i want it in the bq field and do you have any idea what would go in my (Your_Query)